# C# Abstract Class Usage - getting errors Inconsistent Accessibility

Tags: c#

I had one class that was used `ConfirmNonInventoryViewModel`, but then had to come up with another object type that was very similar but with one different property (which may have more unique properties as functionality increases).

So I wanted to turn this original class into the base class and then create 2 derived classes to account for the 2 unique object variants. But since I have code around already using the original class and don't want it to, and so developers don't use that base class directly going forward, I thought that marking it as `abstract` would prevent it from being used and making it so only the derived variants could be used.

But this is giving me errors like `Inconsistent Accessibility: base class is less accessible than derived class`. So I guess I have misunderstood what an abstract class is used for.

How can I meet my requirements as outlined above?

```
public class ConfirmWorkOrderNonInventoryViewModel : ConfirmNonInventoryViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Part:")]
    public int WorkOrderDetailId { get; set; }     
}

public class ConfirmShipOrderNonInventoryViewModel : ConfirmNonInventoryViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Order:")]
    public int OrderHeaderId { get; set; }
}

abstract class ConfirmNonInventoryViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Part:")]
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Material:")]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Est Qty:")]
    public decimal EstimatedQty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Act Qty:")]
    [UIHint("TextBoxFor_50w")]
    public decimal? ConfirmedQty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `public` to your class so it will become:

```
public abstract class ConfirmNonInventoryViewModel{
   //...
}
```

This way your base class has same accessibility as derived classes.

Comment: Thanks...simple...and, well obvious.